# JSP tag attribute inherits variable from parent scope when null is passed in?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I encountered an issue recently where passing `null` into a custom JSP tag resulted in the tag going up the scope and resolving the variable to a variable of the same name in the parent JSP.

Is this expected in Java/JSP/JSTL and is there any way to override this functionality without having to rename my variables to not have naming collisions?

For example, a JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="component" uri="http://www.example.com/test/component"%>

<component:testTag model="${model.testModel}"></component:testTag>
```

that calls this tag file (testTag.tag):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ attribute name="model" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" type="com.example.test.model.component.TestModel" %>

Is model empty? <c:out value="${empty model}"/>
```

What I'm seeing is that despite `model.testModel` being null in the JSP, in the tag `model` is *not null* and it actually resolves to the object that `model` represents in the JSP!? In case it helps, I'm using Spring MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ${model.testModel} is null in the JSP?  Have you tried this syntax for passing in variables:

```
<jsp:directive.attribute name="model" type="com.example.test.model.component.TestModel" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" />
```